# jQuery Opacity Animate

Tags: jquery

Okay, my objective is to have a user click on a div and have another div's opacity change from 0 to 1,but its not really working out.

```
HTML
    <div id="container">

    <div id="middlebottom"><div id="portfolio">Portfolio</div></div>



    </div>

    <div id="portfoliocontainer"> </div>



JQUERY        
    $('#middlebottom').click(function() {
      $('#portfoliocontainer').animate({
        opacity: 1.0;
      });
    });


CSS
    #portfoliocontainer {
    height: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #FF2D2D;
    opacity:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0); }

    #portfolio {
    margin: 30px; }

    #middlebottom {
    width: 40%;
    height: 30%;
    background-color: #FF2D2D;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .7s;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: normal;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    color: #FF9898; }
```

I'm a newbie at jQuery, so I'm not really sure what's gone wrong. I think I've got it right, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think that the problem is the 'height: 0%;'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use fadeIn() ?

Edit:
Here is the code I tried and works for me:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" /> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="middlebottom">
        Your middle bottom div
    </div>

    <div id="portfoliocontainer" style="display: none;">
        Your Portfolio container
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#middlebottom').click(function(){ 
        $('#portfoliocontainer').fadeIn(); 
    }); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $('#middlebottom').click(function() {
      $('#portfoliocontainer').fadeIn();
 });

Comment: And animate() need a time parameter, I think it's because you didn't use one that it's not working.             Edit: I just checked I'm wrong it's not necessary.

Comment: $('#middlebottom').click(function() { 
$('#portfoliocontainer').fadeIn(300); });

Comment: If you use fadeIn() you need to change the CSS for the div#portfoliocontainer: remove opacity: 0 and type display: none

Comment: I did that, but it still wouldn't work. Is it because I had the user have to click a div (no link) to activate it?

Comment: No clicking a div is fine. You must have another mistake somewhere because I tested and it works. Try to see if you have an error message with the console maybe?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any error messages. If it's too much to ask, could you check it again for me? I can't seem to spot anything that could be causing an error http://www.paperstars.org/

Comment: It still doesn't work... could it be because I have another div nested inside #middlebottom?

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't see why it's not working, I can't help you! The fact that you have a div inside doesn't matter. Did you try copying exactly what I gave you to test?

Comment: Let me check the changes for when I apply everything else.

Comment: Wait, it works! I didn't put the jQuery at the end. I put it between the head tags. Thanks a billion for putting up with me!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You're biggest issue is that you have a syntax error.  The semi-colon should be removed from the options object you're passing into the animate function:

```
$('#portfoliocontainer').animate({ 
    opacity: 1.0 // instead of opacity: 1.0; 
});
```

I'm hoping that the HTML you supplied was incomplete because even after fixing the syntax issue you won't actually see anything because you've styled the portfolio container to have 0% height.  Content will need to be added to that container or it must be styled differently in order to see the animation.